Degree of freedom. Two sampled test
According to this blog/article:

To calculate degrees of freedom for a 2-sample t-test, use N – 2 because there are now two parameters to estimate.

What parameters are they talking about? 2 means: for group 1 and mean for group 2? Or something other?

The "classical" $t$-test  is used to test the hypothesis, whether the two samples come from the gaussian distributions with the same mean, assuming that the variances are identical (!). Under this hypothesis, the $t$-value follows a $t$-distribution with N-2 degrees of freedom. And the 2 parameters to estimate are:

mean (if it is the same) and
variance (which is assumed to be the same).

If the two variances are not assumed to be the same, everything is more complicated. The $t$-value no longer follows a $t$-distribution. The alternative calculation procedure for this case is called the Welch procedure.

There are a couple of corrections needed to be made in this response;  1) this method is used to test whether the unknown population means of two groups are equal or not, not whether the 2 samples come from a normal distribution. 2) You are loosing two degrees of freedom because you are estimating the mean in group 1 and group 2.  3) The Welch statistic approximately follows a t distribution.

The classical t-test presupposes that both samples come from the gaussian distributions with the same variance and tests whether the means are the same. All the mathematics behind is based on the assumption of gaussianity.

I agree, when calculating df as n-2, we are assuming normality and equal variance, but your wording is misleading, it reads  as if we are testing for normality and equivalent population means. We are not testing for normality.

thanks. Btw, why is it important that the variances are the same? Som formulas doesn't work? But why?

And how to distinguish cases with an assumed chi-square distribution from an F-distribution and from an normal distribution/t-distribution for population? Do I just need to look at shape of the sample distribution and choose a similar one?
